# How can I compare files in VS Code with an alternative editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed a VS Code Extension for modelling BPMN files. BPMN Files are XML based. When I change my model I currently found no way to compare the changes in XML-Format directly. Instead VS Code always tries to open the files with the BPMN Graphical Editor.

Is there a way to explicit tell VS Code to use the Text Editor for file compare instead of an opening the custom editor registered with an Extension?

This is the Extension I am using:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=open-bpmn.open-bpmn-vscode-extension

This is my VS Code version:

```
Version: 1.78.2
Commit: b3e4e68a0bc097f0ae7907b217c1119af9e03435
Date: 2023-05-10T14:47:05.613Z
Electron: 22.5.2
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 4.19.0-24-amd64
Sandboxed: Yes
```

Comment: in all cases VSCode opens a compare window with the visual editor. But I need the text compare. From the commandline I can use `git diff`  to get the information I expected. But not within VSCode

Comment: Between the `git diff` command and the vscode text-compare-editor there is a big difference in functionality. Maybe you missed this ;-)

Comment: I do not have the command `View: Reopen Editor With...` in my visual studio code

Comment: No, an upgrade to 1.79.2 did not change the situation. Note: I am in a visual file compare mode where a split window shows the BPMN model left and right. This is funny but did not help. I need a to open the compare in text mode. I am the developer of the extension and maybe there is some trick to configure the extension is specific way?

Answer (score 2):

From my research, this is not supported for the SCM diff feature at the time of this writing.

This has to do with [the Custom Editor API](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/custom-editors), so I googled "`vscode custom editor api diff`", and found this issue ticket: [Feature Request: Allow Custom Editors To Gracefully Handle Diff Views #138525](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138525), which is about things from the extension author's point of view, and asks for dedicated support for extensions to control their diff viewers, or opt out of using their custom editor for diffs and instead use the builtin text editor. Give the issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it, and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like "+1" / "bump".

It also seems that the compare files feature (different than the SCM diff feature) opens with the text editor by default for the comparison. You can compare files either by using the `File: Compare Active File With...` command in the command palette, or right click the file in the Explorer View and click "Select for Compare", and then right click another (or the same) file and click "Compare with Selected". In the compare files view, you can also switch to a different custom editor using the `View: Reopen Editor With...` command in the command palette.