# Different defaults for editing and comparing?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am working with a file type that is shown by default as a graphical format. Actually, the underlying format is XML. Whenever I open such file for viewing/editing, I am happy it shows in that graphical format. However, if I compare such file with another version or another file, I would like to see the differences as text. Is there a way to set these defaults?

Background: the specific file type is `.dmn`, which is editable by using the [kogito bundle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kie-group.vscode-extension-kogito-bundle) extention.

Comment: similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75875169/11107541

Comment: Thanks @starball, for this link. I searched, but obviously missed that one. It is exactly the same question. (except I use a different extention)

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, are you talking about the VS Code SCM diff feature, or the "Compare files" feature? Or both? I'm considering asking via issue ticket on the GitHub repo of the extension. Or [you can do it if you want](https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-tools/issues/new) (if you do, please [edit] a link to the issue ticket into your question post).

Comment: also, do the `View: Reopen Editor With...` or `View: Reopen Editor With Text Editor` commands in the command palette help at all here?

Comment: I've written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76608315/11107541). see if it helps you.