# VSCode "compare with saved" functionality for Jupyter notebooks

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I tried to use the "compare with saved" function in the VSCode "Open Editors" section of the file explorer. It works for normal text files, such as .py files, but for a Jupyter notebook (.ipynb files) it does not seem to give me any changes.

The diff view opens, but I see twice the saved (stored) file with no differences between them. Also, it's not formatted as a notebook but as the raw notebook text in json format. Comparing two saved notebooks gives me the notebook viewer, with a correct differences view.

What am I doing wrong, if anything? Can anyone reproduce this problem?(Please give a comment if so, or an answer for an explanation/workaround/fix.)

Comment: loosely related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75875169/11107541, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/158496, but not answer material